# ajax calling of php function from a php page

Tags: php, ajax

This is my jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "process.php",
  success: function(msg){
  }  
});
```

In process.php page I have more than one function.  One function is sendmail().

How can I call this function through ajax?  I wrote the code as:
`url: "process.php/sendmail",` 
but nothing happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `Ajax` call pass some `data` to `process.php`.

```
$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",  
  url: "process.php",
  data: {method: 'one'},
  success: function(msg){
  }  
});
```

In php page,

```
if(isset($_POST["method"])) {
    $method = $_POST["method"];
    if($method=="one") {
       //call methods/functions here
    }
}
```

Comment: but when iam using this i got a error is below Notice: Undefined index: method in E:\wamp\www\promo\install\process.php on line 4

Comment: @KichuUser - What is at line 4 in process.php?

Comment: $method = $_POST["method"];
this is the code iam wrote in line 4 for checking if the method have any value

Comment: ok i got the mistake in your code.there is no need for "" in this code data: "{method: 'one'}",

Answer (score 8):

this is your script file

```
 $.ajax({
       url: "process.php",
       type: "POST",
       data: "functionName=sendmail",
       cache: true,
       success: function(response){

       }
```

and this is your process.php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
   if($_POST["functionName"] == "sendmail")
   {
      sendmail();
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

May below code helpful to you..

```
 $.ajax({  
      type: "POST",  
      url: "process.php",
      data: {action: 'sendmail'},
      success: function(msg){
      }  
    });
```

Try this..

Thanks.

Comment: when iam using this nothing will happen

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic means of telling PHP to call your functions, but you can accomplish this with a simple check.  Since you are trying URLs like "process.php/sendmail" you can test on the PHP variable $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']

```
if ('sendmail' == $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) {
    sendmail();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using if else and process.php?fun=sendmail

```
if($_GET['fun'] == "Sendmail")
  sendmail()
else
  // something else
```

Answer (score 0):

to call send mail function pass a parameter to process.php file, and detect that parameter like:

```
$.ajax({  
type: "POST",  
url: "process.php",
type: "POST",
data: {sendMail: "1"},
success: function(msg){
}  
});
```

now in process.php USE:

```
$_REQUEST['sendMail']
```

to detect the value..